# PowerShell: How do I sort a text file by column?

Tags: file, sorting, text, powershell

I want to sort a text file in PowerShell. The text file looks like this:

```
name1 4
name2 2.3
name3 6.7
name4 5.1
```

I want to output that file like this:

```
name3 6.7
name4 5.1
name1 4
name2 2.3
```

As you can see, it is ordered descending by the number associated to the name.How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can sort by an expression, split each line (space delimiter), cast the last item to system.double and sort on it:

```
Get-Content .\file.txt | Sort-Object { [double]$_.split()[-1] } -Descending
```

Answer (score 0):

another variant:

```
gc c:\f1.txt | add-member scriptproperty sortby {$this.split()[-1]} {[double]$this} -pass | sort sortby -desc
```